# Hide Second Element Until First Element is Finished Animating - CSS Keyframes

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I'm trying to get the second element to not show at all on the screen until the first element is finished animating. So far I've tried this:

```css
@keyframes slideInFromRight {
    0% {
      transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

.announcements-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 80px;
    right: 20px;
    z-index: 1001;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 300px;
}

.announcements-1 {
    animation: 0.4s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromRight;
  }
  
.announcements-2 {
    margin-top: 15px;
    /* opacity: 0; */
    /* display: none; */
    /* animation-fill-mode: both; */
    animation: 0.4s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromRight;
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

.annoucements-header {
    background-color: #1481C3;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Proxima Nova Bold";
    padding: 7px 10px;
}

.annoucements-close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 36px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: .85;
}
.annoucements-close:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.annoucements-close::before,
.annoucements-close::after {
    content: '';
    width: 24px;
    height: 2px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    left: 0;
}
.annoucements-close::before {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.annoucements-close::after {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="announcements-container">
    <div class="announcements-1">
      <div class="annoucements-header">
        <span class="annoucement-type-quantity">2 School Announcements</span>
        <i class="annoucements-close"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="announcements-2">
      <div class="annoucements-header">
        <span class="annoucement-type-quantity">1 Admin Annoucement</span>
        <i class="annoucements-close"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

But as you can see, the second div still shows while the first div is sliding in from the right. I've tried adding `animation-delay`, `transition-delay`, changing the delay value to `0.4` in the line `animation: 0.4s ease-out 0.4s 1 slideInFromRight;`, or adding a new keframe entirely:

```css
@keyframes slideInFromRight {
    0% {
      transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes slideInFromRight2 {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

.announcements-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 80px;
    right: 20px;
    z-index: 1001;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 300px;
}

.announcements-1 {
    animation: 0.4s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromRight;
  }
  
.announcements-2 {
    margin-top: 15px;
    /* opacity: 0; */
    /* display: none; */
    /* animation-fill-mode: both; */
    -webkit-animation: slideInFromRight2 0.4s ease-out 1s 1 normal;
    -moz-animation: slideInFromRight2 0.4ss ease-out 1s 1 normal;
    -o-animation: slideInFromRight2 0.4s ease-out 1s 1 normal;
    animation: slideInFromRight2 0.4s ease-out 1s 1 normal;
}

.annoucements-header {
    background-color: #1481C3;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Proxima Nova Bold";
    padding: 7px 10px;
}

.annoucements-close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 36px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: .85;
}
.annoucements-close:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.annoucements-close::before,
.annoucements-close::after {
    content: '';
    width: 24px;
    height: 2px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    left: 0;
}
.annoucements-close::before {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.annoucements-close::after {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="announcements-container">
    <div class="announcements-1">
      <div class="annoucements-header">
        <span class="annoucement-type-quantity">2 School Announcements</span>
        <i class="annoucements-close"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="announcements-2">
      <div class="annoucements-header">
        <span class="annoucement-type-quantity">1 Admin Annoucement</span>
        <i class="annoucements-close"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

But it's still showing up during the first animation. Is there any way to make the element disappear until it's 'turn' to go? Possible to do this entirely with CSS or will it require JavaScript?

[Link to JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HappyHands31/avws6h3f/15/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's pure CSS approach to this issue, the approach is that initially to  every element you want to animate, give an `opacity: 0` and then in the `@keyframes` animation, set its opacity to 1 as soon as the animation starts. Then the animation would look something like:

```
@keyframes slideInFromRight {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  .1%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

And to every element you want to animate add `opacity: 0` in your css
Also don't forget to use `animation-fill-mode: forwards`

Comment: Hello, please check out this JSFiddle - I think you're suggesting creating two separate `@keyframes` animations, then? https://jsfiddle.net/HappyHands31/avws6h3f/15/ But they are animating at the same time like this.

Comment: @HappyHands31 no a single animation will do the job see here https://jsfiddle.net/89hvufbo/14/

Comment: Oh so the key was to do what you suggested above for the `keyframes` _in accordance with_ adding `animation-delay: .4s;` to the second div - thanks!

Comment: @HappyHands31 yeah and note another thing that we defined the animation style before `opacity: 0` in both the announncement classes so that it can override the `opacity: 0` when animation takes place